# MongoDB - Array of object filter with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a json file that look like this in my collection :

```
[
   {
      "change":"00001",
      "patchset":"4"
   },
   //etc
]
```

Two different object can have the same "change" properties.
So first I want to group them by "change" properties and inside this group I want the highest value of the "patchset" properties. I have managed to do this easily with this command

```
db.collections.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$change",patchset_max:{$max:"$patchset"}}}])
```

but then, and this is where I lost it, with this max patchset, I want to get all the objects where object.patchset = max_patchset but still in the group array.

I tried with $filter and $match and then nested $group but nothing works,

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Answer above is correct, but if on Mongo 3.2, here's an alternative

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ 
    $group: { _id: "$change", patchset: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, patchset_max:{ $max:"$patchset" } } 
},{ 
    $project: {
        patchset: {
            $filter: { 
                input: '$patchset',
                as: 'ps',
                cond: { $eq: ['$$ps.patchset', '$patchset_max'] }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Works like a charm in my version 4.0.2. the $project and $filter framework for aggregate with cond is very smart indeed ! Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$$ROOT` which is a special variable that represents whole document to get all the items for each group and then you can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to overwrite existing array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get only those docs that have `patchset` equal to `patchset_max`. Try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$change",
            patchset_max:{$max:"$patchset"},
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            docs: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$docs",
                    as: "doc",
                    cond: {
                        $eq: [ "$patchset_max", "$$doc.patchset" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Sample playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u3otqbOaVHK)

Comment: Just as the OP didn't mention the version of Mongo being used, worth noting that $addFields was added in 3.4

Comment: Thanks mickl. Yes I forgot the version, it's 4.0.3, and your solution works well, but @sofcal's solution is shorter and works the same since I have the good version ! But thank you !